# Remove space between wrapper and main container

Tags: html, css

I am new CSS and I am learning CSS for my website. Recently I found a CSS issue with my website after updating it to the latest version. There is a space between the main container and wrapper. See the below image.

[image: Space between container and wrapper image]

How can I get the space between the wrapper and the main container? Firefox inspection gives me this,

```
.d-header > .wrap {
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    height: 100%;
}
```

I tried the below custom CSS to solve this problem, but no effect.

```
.d-header .wrap {
    max-width: 1144px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

I don't know why I can't change the max-width of the wrapper. Need some help to fix this issue?

Comment: I think margin padding issue

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't changing the width to `100%` solve your problem?

```css
.wrapper{
  width: 300px;
  background: green;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.header1, .header2{
  background: yellow;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.header1{
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
}

.header2{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header1">
    Header with <code>width: calc(100% - 16px)</code>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header2">
    Header with <code>width: 100%</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `margin:0;` to the wrapper and `padding:0`; to the container